# Update from Assets 1.2.2 to 2.0, Files are not showing

Tags: assets

I have updated Assets from version 1.2.2 to 2.0 following the [steps on the P&T website](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets/docs/updating).

After going to 'Add-Ons -> Modules', selecting 'Run Module Updates' and confirming 'Update' on the Assets warning page, I received various PHP errors (which I stupidly did not copy). I was able to re-load that page and view the updated UI for Assets.

I no longer see any of the files and images that were present in Assets 1.2.2 in the File Manager. Images on the front end are also now missing. Viewing the database, it looks like everything ing the `exp_assets_files` table is gone.

I have also run 'Updated Indexes' for both of my directories handled via Assets and cleared my browser cache.

I am attempting the update locally via a MAMP install running PHP 5.3.14 and **do** have a db backup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Follow up, I rolled back to my commit before trying to update to 2.0 and also restored the db.

Same error messages which I have captured this time:

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: 1:client-logos
Filename: assets/upd.assets.php
Line Number: 709`

This same error repeats for different directories I had created in Assets 1.2.2.

Comment: What does your Assets folder structure look like?

Comment: If you want to go ahead and send your db backup over to support@pixelandtonic.com, I can look into this and see what's going on.

Comment: Hi Brad,

I have sent you the db backup. Thanks for looking into this.

The Assets folder structure is:

/assets/uploads/images/
/assets/uploads/files/

Various subfolders were created via Assets inside each of these directories.

Comment: Please direct bug reports directly to developers - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up, Brad from P&T was able to send me a build that updated successfully. Thanks to him and P&T for doing this so quickly!

Answer (score 1):

This is because your Upload Filedirs have relative paths in Server Path field - this was somehow forgotten in the whole process. This will be fixed in the upcoming release, but, in the meantime, you can just set it to an absolute path and that should work for you.

Comment: Andris, can you be a bit more specific? Are you referring to setting File Upload paths in the config file?

Comment: Chad, I mean in EE's File Upload preferences, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The config settings actually apply directly to File Upload settings, so by setting `'server_path'     => $config['server_path']."assets/uploads/images/",` and `'url'       => $config['site_url']."/assets/uploads/images/"`, etc., it does apply the full paths in 'File Uploads'.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running EE 2.5.4 and I just upgraded to Assets 2. The upgrade went smoothly and is operational.

I can view my files in both thumbnails modes (small and big) but I have an error showing up when I try to view files in a list.

```
    load->view('listview/files'); ?>
```

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAzHz.png

Comment: Release Assets 2.0.2 today which should fix this for you.

Comment: This isn't really appropriate as an answer.  Next time I recommend you use the add comment link.